# Is "throw in X at Y" idiomatic?

Tags: grammar, phrases, idiomatic-language

Is "throw in X at Y" idiomatic? I am wondering if I am using the phrase idiomatically or not. It's difficult for a non-native English speaker to determine if a phrase is idiomatic or not, so I rather ask it here.

For example:

> The writers of the show decided to throw in **a bunch of stereotypical
>   evil antagonists** at **the protagonist** of the series to make the
>   show more interesting.

Comment: You would "throw X at Y." Not throw in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"in"-"at" doesn't go. However, you could use one or the other.

> The writers of the show decided to throw a bunch of stereotypical evil antagonists **at** the protagonist of the series to make the show more interesting.

or

> The writers of the show decided to throw **in** a bunch of stereotypical evil antagonists (to make the show more interesting).

Comment: Additional examples are “throw in the towel” and “throw something at the wall and see if it sticks”.